# Borderless window in Wix Toolset

Tags: wix

I am using wix to create a windows installer and I want it to be borderless. Is this possible? If so, how can I create an area on the window where I can drag it from?

Answer (score -1):

Yes.It is possible. Have a look at this.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Height="350" Width="525" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" >
<Grid >
    <Rectangle Fill="Gray" MouseDown="Rectangle_MouseDown" />
    <Grid Margin="10" Background="LightGray">
     ---your window elements go here---
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Inside the Rectangle elements mouse down event handler goes your code to drag the window. So if you click on the rectangle i.e the area surrounding your inner Grid, you will be able to drag your window.

```
private void Rectangle_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
            this.DragMove();
    }
```

Comment: I decided to switch to Wix# in order to get more control but thanks you for the answer, hope it helps somebody :)

Comment: It is not a WPF Application. Question says WIX Installer.